# If $A$ be nonnegative and tridiagonal . Can we say that, all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose  $A\in M_n$ is nonnegative(all $a_{ij}\ge0$) and tridiagonal.

Can we say  that, all the eigenvalues of
$A$ are real?

Comment: Horn, Roger A.; Johnson, Charles R. (1985). Matrix Analysis. Cambridge University Press. p. 174.
The answer is yes.

Comment: @Hetebrij , All right ,Why is true?

Comment: When you say that $A$ is non-negative, don't you assume that $A$ is symmetric and so the eigenvalues of $A$ are real? Or you mean that $A$ is not necessarily symmetric?

Comment: @H.S The gist of the argument is as follows: start with the case that $A > 0$.  We can find a diagonal matrix $D$ for which $DAD^{-1}$ is symmetric, which means that $A$ has real eigenvalues.  Then, it suffices to apply the continuity of eigenvalues by taking limits.

Comment: @levap Nonnegative means $A_{i,j} \ge 0$ for all $i,j \le n$. Positive semi-definite means that $A$ is symmetric with nonnegative eigenvalues.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - $A$ is nonnegative i.e; all $a_{ij}\ge0$.I edited this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Consider first the case in which the super and sub diagonals are strictly positive, that is, $a_{i,i+1},a_{i+1,i} > 0$ for $i = 1,\dots,n-1$.  Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $d_{ii} = d_i$.  Let $B = DAD^{-1}$. Note that
$$
b_{i,i+1} = \frac{d_i}{d_{i+1}}a_{i,i+1}\\
b_{i+1,i} = \frac{d_{i+1}}{d_{i}}a_{i+1,i}
$$
With that in mind, define the entries $d_i$ by
$$
d_1 = 1\\
d_{i+1} = \sqrt{\frac{a_{i,i+1}}{a_{i+1,i}}} d_i
$$
and verify that for these $d_i$, $B$ is a symmetric matrix.

To complete the proof, it suffices to note that eigenvalues vary continuously as a function of the entries of a matrix.